# How to inject a NamedHttpClient to TypedHttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

In my .Net core application I have NamedHttpClient and I have a TypedHttpClient. I need to use the NamedClient as the default httpclient inside TypedHttpClient.

My configure services:

```
public static IServiceCollection ConfigureServiceOptions(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config)
{
    IConfigurationSection serverSection = config.GetSection(nameof(ServerOptions));
    services.Configure<ServerOptions>(serverSection);
    
    
    //Named
    services.AddHttpClient("defaultHttpClient", client =>
    {

        client.BaseAddress = new System.Uri(dataServerSection.Get<ServerOptions>().ServerUrl);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/xml, */*");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Server v1.0.0");
    });
    
}



//startup.cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.ConfigureServiceOptions(Configuration);
    
    //Adding Typed
    services.AddHttpClient<DataService>(); //I need to use defaultHttpClient as HttpClient Inside DataService
}
```

So far I found 3 ways to do this, not sure if there is any pitfall in any of the method

Way 1:

```
services.AddHttpClient<DataService>();

public class DataService
{
    private HttpClient Client { get;}
    public DataService(/*need to pass this otherwise cant resolve*/ HttpClient client, IHttpClientFactory factory)
    {
        Client = factory.CreateClient("defaultHttpClient");
    }
}
```

In Way 1 i need to have the additional HttpClient client parameter in the constructor. Otherwise the DataService is not resolved.

Way2:

```
services.AddTransient<DataService>( cfg =>
{
    var clientFactory = cfg.GetRequiredService<System.Net.Http.IHttpClientFactory>();
    var httpClient = clientFactory.CreateClient("defaultHttpClient");
    return new DataService(httpClient);
});

public class DataService
{
    private HttpClient Client { get;}
    public DataService(HttpClient client)
    {
        Client = client;
    }
}
```

Way 3:

```
services.AddTransient<DataService>();

public class DataService
{
    private HttpClient Client { get;}
    public DataService(IHttpClientFactory factory)
    {
        Client = factory.CreateClient("defaultHttpClient");
    }
}
```

I think Way2 and Way3 might be same. Not sure if there is any difference.

Can someone tell what is the recommended way ? or if there is any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not actually setting up the typed client for `DataService` the "Way 1" does not make much sense, it is basically "Way 3" but with extra steps.

"Way 2" make service code cleaner but will become cumbersome to maintain if new dependencies will be needed for it later.

"Way 3" is how using named `HttpClient` is shown in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0#createclient) so I would go with it.

Comment: Why in way1, the dummy HttpClient is required?

Comment: @samnaction because you are registering your service as consumer of typed `HttpClient` (actually internally it will add named registration based on type name) with `.AddHttpClient<DataService>` and the framework will try to provide `HttpClient` as ctor parameter for `DataService`.